PLC Panel Contintuity Tester
I'm trying to build a simple Unistream PLC panel continuity tester, I'm simply struggling to understand how PLC works and create a simple continuity tester for it.
The test jig simply provides 24V to the Unit Under Test(PLC Panel) and the PLC panel output (sampling level sensor) would be tested if all connections leading to the connector have continuity.
Continuity Test A: Simple continuity test to see if 24V is being supplied to the PLC. It checks the 3 wires of the level sensor connector. LT11-24V LT11-GND LT11-OUT All three wires need to be tested so as you can see in the photo. The SPDT switches from LT11-OUT to LT11-GND. will PLC let the LED light up or would it be too low of a current to light up a 24V LED?

Continuity Test B: Here I've done a little research of how PLC works and to my understanding the common terminal(CM0) of the I0 to an 24V to be in a Source Mode as seen in the PLC data sheet image.
Basically, I'm just asking how should do a continuity of test I/O of the PLC?

enter image description here


(As this question has been substantially edited, obsolete comments referring to issues with the previous version have been deleted as they no longer apply and would be confusing to readers.)

Why are the "schematics" still upside-down?

JBEE - Hi, Where is this image from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to the relevant item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, , edition. (More rules in the [tour] & [help].)

Please check added link is OK. || You MUST provide source information (a link is an acceptable method) for All images.



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. Test circuit schematic.
How it works

J0 to J3 are your test connectors.
X0 to X3 are your test indicators. These will test supply on pins 1 and 2. Add a diode to each if you want it to light only when the correct polarity is applied.
SW0 to SW3 will ground each of the source-configured inputs. If there are input indicator lamps on the PLC the corresponding indicator will illuminate as each button is pressed.

Notes:

Schematic is right way up.
Schematic reads from left to right.
Where possible, higher voltages are on the top and current flows from top to bottom.
Schematic symbols are used, not cartoons.
The layout is organised so that the schema (circuit intent) is very clear.


Thank you very much ! I was also wondering, if the input is in sink mode, placing the GND to MC0. would the input(I0,I1,I2,I3) put out 24V instead?

I don't know. You didn't provide a link to the PLC user manual and your diagrams are still upside down.

My apologies, here's the link for the PLC manual.
https://www-unitronicsplc-com.webpkgcache.com/doc/-/s/www.unitronicsplc.com/Documents/UniStream/Built-in/IG_US5_7_10-Bx-RA28_TA30.pdf
